# C program Bluetooth socket error : protocol not supported (but "work" on linux mint)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Hello I'm here to ask some help about my program here :
https://github.com/Vampire142/SchoolProject2017

Especially here :

```
sock = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
```

On linux mint 18:
Code work like a charm, except I don't get anythings to the connected devices
(but no sending error, pretty strange situation...)

On raspbian :
After compiling it i get error, need to add -std=c99, and after this i get a working executable file, but after running this one, i get a Protocol not supported.

I don't understand very well where the problem is...
The only good tutorial i found for Bluez on linux is a guide by Albert Huang
Called "An Introduction to Bluetooth Programming"

I put all installed package on the raspberry on this pastebin :
https://pastebin.com/m7QXc3hN

Some help will be very grateful :)

Comment: I think it is telling you *exactly* what the problem is...

Comment: Looked all over the web, no found any good explanation. It's "work" on Linux mint, but not in raspbian for exact same packages and version

Comment: `sudo apt-get install bluez`

Comment: Ho pretty strange, "Lasted version already installed"... Don't act like I am stupid. I read all over the web since 1 hours for help...

Comment: I understood i doesn't ask with good information, i edited the post, now it's seems to be clear for me, stop look down on me. Thanks you

Comment: I don't understand the down votes.  The question is pretty clear.  I would however post the output in a pastebin of each environment though.

Comment: No problem here:pi@RPI_02:~ $ ./rfcomm-server 
Starting Bluetooth Server
readInput() : buffer = YnLa8Yl9
readInput() : buffer = EbE_A_^V
readInput() : buffer = ?I_U0u=G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, strange things have occur, a new update came out for raspbian, i let the raspberry update alone, and now the program no sending error...
Maybe a bug in kernel/package ?